# Am I properly using fscanf? and the switch statement?

Tags: c, switch-statement, double, scanf

I was assigned a bank account assignment, where I get the users input of whether they want to deposit (D) or withdraw (C) . After they choose it is suppose to display the balance of their bank account.

What I am having trouble with is i keep getting build errors dealing with my fopen and fscanf. What is the problem with my code?

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C4996   'fscanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fscanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.   checkingAccount c:\users\csis\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\checkingaccount\checkingaccount\checkingaccount.c   21

```
    #include <stdio.h>

FILE *fpin;
FILE *fpout;

double deposit;
double withdraw;
double balance;


//Function that asks the user for deposit information then prints balance + deposit.
double D(double balance, double deposit) {
printf("and the amount is:");
fscanf(fpout, "%lf", &deposit);
printf("The balance is: %lf", balance);
return 0;
}

//Function that asks user for the amount they want withdrawn, then prints balance - withdrawal amount.
double C(double balance, double withdraw) {
    printf("and the amount is:");
    fscanf(fpout, "%lf", &withdraw);
    printf("The balance is %lf", balance);
    return 0;
}



int main(void) {

    char code;

    deposit = 0;
    withdraw = 0;
    balance = 0;

    //formula for balance.
    balance = balance + deposit;
    balance = balance - withdraw;

//opens documents for inputs.
fpin = fopen("transactions.txt", "r");
fpout = fopen("processed.txt", "w");


printf("Welcome to Chris's Checking Account Tracer Program");
printf("\n------------------------------------------------------\n");

//runs infinite loop.
for (;;) {
    printf("The transaction is a: ");
    //Sends user input of code to transcations text document.
    fscanf(fpin, '%c', &code);


    // If user enters D runs 'D' Function.
    switch (code) {
    case 'D':
        D(balance, deposit);
        break;

        // If user enters C runs 'C' Function.
    case 'C':
        C(balance, withdraw);
        break;
        // If user enters anything else other then D or C prints "Not responding correctly".
    default:
        printf("Not responding Correctly.");
        break;
    }
}
//closes the text documents.
fclose(fpin);
fclose(fpout);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "What I am having trouble with is i keep getting build errors dealing with my fopen and fscanf." --> post the errors.

Comment: `=` doesn't set up a formula, it performs a calculation then and there using the current values

Comment: Be careful when using floating point values for money: you cannot store a value of `0.01` exactly in a `double`. Because of that, adding a cent 100 times will *not* give you a whole dollar.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem.  In the `for` loop in `main`:

```
fscanf(fpin, '%c', &code);
```

Single quotes are used for character constants.  For a string, you need double quotes:

```
fscanf(fpin, "%c", &code);
```

Comment: ... Also a good idea to check the return value from `fscanf`

Comment: a good idea is to compile with more warnings (for example `gcc -Wall`)  and fix the problems diagnosed with the compiler.